# Encontrar char em uma string, nunca encontra

Tags: c, string, comparação, char

Fiz uma função procura um caractere em uma string. Os parâmetros de entrada são a string e o caractere. A função retorna 1 (um) se o caractere existir na string ou zero caso contrário. O usuário deve inserir, através do teclado, a string e o caractere.

Segue os código abaixo, fiz normal e usando ponteiros, mas independente do caractere que digito está caindo no else?:   printf("\n\n O caracter nao foi encontrado.\n");

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int localiza(char string[], char letra){//funcao verifica se a palavra contem a letra
int i;
for( i=0; string[i] != '\ 0';i++){
    if(string[i] == 'letra'){
      printf("\n\n O caracter foi encontrado: %s \n",string[i]);
      return 1;
    }else{
      printf("\n\n O caracter nao foi encontrado.\n");
      return 0;
    }
}

}


main(){
char str[20];
char ctr;
int k,i,num;

printf("\n Informe a string: ");
gets (str);

printf("\n Informe o caractere que deseja procurar: ");
scanf("%c",&ctr);

localiza(str,ctr);//chama a funcao de verificar se a letra esta na palavra

printf("\n\n");
system("pause");
}
```

Outro codigo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int localiza(char *s1, char *s2){//funcao verifica se a palavra contem a letra
int i;
    if(strstr(s1, s2)){
        printf("\n\n O caracter foi encontrado! \n");
        return 1;
    }else{
        printf("\n\n O caracter nao foi encontrado!\n");
        return 0;
    }
   }


main(){
char str[20];
char ctr[1];
int k,i,num;

printf("\n Informe a string: ");
gets (str);

printf("\n Informe o caractere que deseja procurar: ");
gets(ctr);
//scanf("%c",&ctr);

char *ptr_str=str;
char *ptr_ctr=ctr;

localiza(str,ctr);//chama a funcao de verificar se a letra esta na palavra

printf("\n\n");
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: bigown não esta duplicada, essa outra não responde minha dúvida..
Meu problema não está em comparar strings.
Comparo um caractere com uma string e nunca está encontrado valor igual.

Comment: Onde você compara?

Comment: No primeiro codigo:

    if(string[i] == 'letra'){
      printf("\n\n O caracter foi encontrado: %s \n",string[i]);
      return 1;
    }else{
      printf("\n\n O caracter nao foi encontrado.\n");
      return 0;
    }

No segundo codigo:
    if(strstr(s1, s2)){
        printf("\n\n O caracter foi encontrado! \n");
        return 1;
    }else{
        printf("\n\n O caracter nao foi encontrado!\n");
        return 0;
    }

Comment: Aí está comparando *strings*, do jeito errado, mas é exatamente o que está naquela pergunta.

Comment: hum.. continuo sem entender, obrigado